# paypal phonegap plugin - PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE error

Tags: android, cordova, paypal

we have a web app base on phonegap and we want to use in paypal plugin for payment-
for android platform.

And i found a guide for it in:
[in githab](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK-PhoneGap)

The sdk is fine, and recognize.

Everything was ok till i insert the com.paypal.android.sdk.phonegap

Then I get an error that Payment Activity.ENVIRONMENT LIVE is :ENVIRONMENT_LIVE cannot be resolved or is not a field.

i'm using in phonegap -v: 3.3.0-0.18.0

thanks

Comment: Can you please post your code where you are setting the environment?

Comment: what do you mean by  inserting the com.paypal.android.sdk.phonegap??